# How to make svg fit container in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

[image]

See the image above. That is the svg container I have highlighted but I only want the svg to take up it's actual size (i.e. just the inner white triangle)

I've tried changing parent width and height but nothing seems to work. how do I fix this?

this is the markup:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24" fill="#fff">
   <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
   <path d="M12 16l-6-6h12z"></path>
</svg>
```

the second path seems to be the exact width and height of what I need

second edit:

```
export const Icon = ({ name }) => {
  let Icon: any = icons[name]
  return (
    <div
      className={css`
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      `}
    >
      <Icon height={24} fill="red" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

and `icons` is

```
import { ReactComponent as MyIcon } from "./my-icon.svg"

const icons = {
  "my-icon": MyIcon
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could post your code along with the .css

Comment: It looks like you are using it as an icon follwoing some text. Can you post a [mcve] snippet, showing the SVG being used in context please?

Answer (score 0):

`M12 16l-6-6h12z` represents your triangle and means

1. move to the point with coordinates 12 16
2. then draw the line to -6 -6 (relatively to current point)
3. then draw the horizontal line with the length equals to 12 then
4. to go the first point

And you get your icon as the result.

There are several ways you can fit the path, but you should understand how a `path` works. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path).

And see examples below

First way to fit:

```css
svg {
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24" fill="#red">
   <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
   <path d="M 12 24 l -12 -24 h24 z"></path>
</svg>
```

Second:

```css
svg {
 border: 1px solid red;
 }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24" fill="#red">
   <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
   <path d="M 12 12 l -12 -12 h24 z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: looks better but you have inverted the triangle colors I think ?

Comment: The *#fff* triangle doesn't look nicely with the *#fff* background

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the SVG that the `width` and `height` are currently set to 24.
A good start would be to set the width and height to `1em` to better match the font size.  *See first example in the demo below.*

If you feel the triangle is too small now, you can make it appear bigger by adjusting the `viewBox`. At the moment it has quite a bit of padding around it. To shring that padding, increase the viewBox `x` and `y` (first two numbers) and reduce the `width` and `height` (second two numbers.  *In the second example below, I have shrunk the padding by 3 units all around the icon by increasing the `x` and `y` by 3, and reducing the `width` and `height`, by 2 * 3 correspondingly.*

The icon is now bigger compared to the text, But it can appear a bit high now.
There are a few ways to adjust that.  Including the following:

- Use `position: relative` and `top: 2px` to push the `<svg>` down a bit.
- Reduce the icon size to something like `0.7em`, so that the icon matches better the X height of the font, rather than the full Em height.
- Use a different `vertical-align` setting to adjust the position of the icon relative to the rest of the line. *In example 3 below, I have set the icon to `vertical-align: text-top`.*
- Push the icon lower in the viewBox by increasing the padding at the top of the viewBox.  *In example 4 below I've reduced the `viewBox y` (second number) to increase the top padding.*

```css
body {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

div {
  font: 16px sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

svg {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Show

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24" fill="#fff">
   <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
   <path d="M12 16l-6-6h12z"></path>
  </svg>
</div>


<div>
  Show

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="3 3 18 18" width="24" height="24" fill="#fff">
   <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
   <path d="M12 16l-6-6h12z"></path>
  </svg>
</div>


<div>
  Show

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="3 3 18 18" width="24" height="24" fill="#fff" style="vertical-align: text-top">
   <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
   <path d="M12 16l-6-6h12z"></path>
  </svg>
</div>


<div>
  Show

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="3 1 18 18" width="24" height="24" fill="#fff">
   <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
   <path d="M12 16l-6-6h12z"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```